# Getting User Input Value from Bootstrap Form

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-5

I have the following Code for an input field in Bootstrap:

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="f2">F</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="f2" id="f2">
</div>
```

I also have an external .js script which need to s receive the information the user inputs.
How do I access the user input with my .js script?

Answer (score 0):

By using selector. like that:
`const i = document.getElementById('f2');`

After this you have access to the input element.
`console.log(i.value)`

Answer (score -1):

```
const inputEl = document.getElementById('f2') // get input from the DOM
const inputValue = inputEl.value
```

Comment: This does not work for me. The program doesnt seem to recognize const. I also tried replacing "const" with "var" which I found worked for me on other occasions and still no result.I can do alert(document.getElementById("f2").value); which is the only thing that causes the relevant part of the website to load,but it still only alerts an empty string.

Comment: I can't help you without more information, try setting up a codepen demo and sharing the link so i can check out the code.